# Need to get JSONObjects from this

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite

This is my URL "http://182.18.161.240:7070/sfaweb-1.1.015/get/retailers/dl-0004/2"

I was able to download the data through volley, but while parsing I'm not able to retrieve anything from this. Help would be deeply appreciated.

Response is nothing but the downloaded data.

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);

for(int i=0;i<jsonObject.length();i++) {
    //JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String rtrname=jsonObject.getString("rtrname").toString();
    String ctgname=jsonObject.getString("ctgname").toString();
    String rtrphoneno=jsonObject.getString("rtrphoneno").toString();

    str+= "\n rtrname:"+rtrname+"\n ctgname:"+ctgname+"\n rtrphoneno:" +rtrphoneno+"\n";
    boolean isInserted = database.insertData(rtrname,ctgname,rtrphoneno);
}
```

What am I missing in this?
I have been stuck on this for quite some time, so please help me. I'm kinda new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below Code,

```
   JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);       

  for(int i=0;i < jsonArray.length(); i++) 
  {
    JSONObject jsonObject= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

     //JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
     String rtrname=jsonObject.getString("rtrname").toString();
     String ctgname=jsonObject.getString("ctgname").toString();
     String rtrphoneno=jsonObject.getString("rtrphoneno").toString();

     str+= "\n rtrname:"+rtrname+"\n ctgname:"+ctgname+"\n rtrphoneno:" +rtrphoneno+"\n";
     boolean isInserted = database.insertData(rtrname,ctgname,rtrphoneno);
  }
```

Comment: how is it different from what @Dennis said?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response,lemme try it out

Answer (score 2):

The response you are getting is an array so you should put it in an array:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
```

Comment: hi,so after this i should just put it in a for loop ??

Comment: Yes, just like you did before (but with the JSONArray)